# Creating a Sublime Text Grunt Build System for a specific target

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, gruntjs, sublimetext3

I'm new to Grunt (and fairly new to sublime Text), but I've downloaded the excellent grunt build system and it works well every time I save. I'm on Win8 by the way.

The only problem is that it runs all tasks/targets. I have separated my tasks into "dist" and "dev" targets and I would like it to run only the dev tasks when I use it on save.

I'd then like to create a separate build task which I would use when building for production. Is this a sensible strategy?

Anyway, I just need to know how to modify the following build system file to just run tasks with the "dev" target....

```
{
  "cmd": ["grunt", "--no-color"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}",
  "selector": "Gruntfile.js",
  "windows":
  {
    "cmd": ["grunt.cmd", "--no-color"]
  },
  "variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "Gruntfile",
      "cmd": ["grunt", "--no-color"],
      "windows":
      {
        "cmd": ["grunt.cmd", "--no-color"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to create an task that runs all the dev targets:

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['task:dev', 'task2:dev']);
```

This can be run from the command-line using: `grunt dev`

As for the Sublime build config, `"cmd"` is just an array of command-line arguments.

So it would end up like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["grunt", "dev", "--no-color"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}",
  "selector": "Gruntfile.js",
  "windows":
  {
    "cmd": ["grunt.cmd", "dev", "--no-color"]
  },
  "variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "Gruntfile",
      "cmd": ["grunt", "dev", "--no-color"],
      "windows":
      {
        "cmd": ["grunt.cmd", "dev", "--no-color"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sindre, I'll try that tonight.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call Grunt by specifying it's complete path. Calling `grunt` alone fails, even though you have the `grunt-cli` installed and working from the cmd prompt. Note you need to have the environment variable for nodejs set.

1. Windows users create your `my-project.sublime-builder` file and put it in `C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User`. Apple/Unix location will be different.
2. The `my-project.sublime-builder` file looks like:

```
{
  "cmd": "C:\\Users\\ronni\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\grunt.cmd",
  "working_dir": "C:\\Users\\ronni\\documents\\my-project"
}
```